# Change dynamically added similar ng-repeat values from single source

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change dynamically added similar ng-repeat values separately from shown single source, you can see from my below code, where if we click on dynamically appended divs, it will shows a form in right side, where if we can add input text fields, but what my problem is when i am trying to add or change text it was binding and adding to all divs,, i want to add input fields to the selected div only.

Pls don't use ng-repeat method to push values for 'add again' button, from append method only it has to add..

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fjW1TdVAmnqql2x3VjO?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

     $scope.items = [];
        $scope.add_New = function (index) {
        var itemhtml = '<div ng-click="select()" class="content">//click here// <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}</div></div>';
        var item = $compile(itemhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(item);
          };
        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            name: "hi"
          });
        };
        $scope.select = function(){
          $scope.showItem = true;
        }
});
```

```css
.add{
  position: absolute; height: auto; width: 200px; left: 0; right: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.show{
  position: absolute; width: auto; left: 200px; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
float:right;
}
.content{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
          <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <div class="add"><button ng-click="add_New($index)">add Again</button>
    <div id="drop">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showItem" class="show">
          <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use the same list for all your main items and sub items.
Because you don't want to use ngrepeat, you will have to create an index for all your main items.

Create a list of main. each time you create a main item, you increase the index.

After that, each main item have a list of values (sub item).

Hopefully what you expected !

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bSh3ImB1U5sODLN2nNQO?p=preview)

Here working code :

```
app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.index = 0;
        $scope.currentIndex = -1;

        $scope.add_New = function (index) {
        var itemhtml = '<div ng-click="select(' + $scope.index + ')" class="content">//click here first// <div ng-repeat="item in items[' + $scope.index + '].values">{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}</div></div>';
        var item = $compile(itemhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(item);
        $scope.items[$scope.index] = {};
        $scope.index++;
          };
        $scope.add = function () {
          if ($scope.items[$scope.currentIndex].values == undefined)
            $scope.items[$scope.currentIndex].values = [];

          $scope.items[$scope.currentIndex].values.push({ 
            name: "hi"
          });
        };
        $scope.select = function(index){
          $scope.showItem = true;
          $scope.currentIndex = index;
        }
});

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
    <div class="add"><button ng-click="add_New()">add Again</button>
    <div id="drop">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showItem" class="show">
          <div ng-repeat="item in items[currentIndex].values">
            {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

          </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks alot .. :) what i expected is exactly right ... :) u done a great job,, u r rocking seriously ...